# EF Core Query Performance Enhancement

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have EF core which I need to do heavy operation on it before return the result back for the end user but the issue is, the operation time it's taking too much time, So, How can I enhance the performance.
Note: I tried to add AsNoTracking().AsEnumerable(), but with no luck it needs around 30 seconds until it returns any data.

I have Service which is called by the controller,
the Service using two helpers functions one for preparing the stored procedure query and another one for doing the grouping based on parameter which received from the user:

here is the code:

The Service Core

```cs
public async Task<List<ResultDto>> MyService(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate,string groupingType)
{  
    List<ResultDto> result = new List<ResultDto>();

    try
    {
        SqlParameter[] param = StoredProcedureHelpers.GetAsSQLParameters2(startDate, endDate);

        string sql = "EXEC MyStoredProcedure @StartDate,@EndDate";


        var storedProcedureResult =  _context.MyStoredProceduresResults.FromSqlRaw(sql, param).AsNoTracking().AsEnumerable();

        var distinctedResult = storedProcedureResult.DistinctBy(x => x.Some_Id).OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Take(10).AsEnumerable();


        result = distinctedResult.GroupByChoosedGroupingType(groupingType).OrderBy(x => x.GroupingKey).ToList();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The Stored Procedure Helper function:

```cs
public static SqlParameter[]? GetAsSQLParameters2(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
{

    SqlParameter[] param = Array.Empty<SqlParameter>();
    try
    {

        param = new SqlParameter[]
        {
            new SqlParameter {
                ParameterName = "@StartDate",
                SqlDbType =System.Data.SqlDbType.Date,
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = startDate
            },

            new SqlParameter {
                ParameterName = "@EndDate",
                SqlDbType =System.Data.SqlDbType.Date,
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = endDate
            }
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
    return param;
}
```

Grouping Helper Function:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<ResultDto> GroupByChoosedGroupingType(this IEnumerable<MyStoredProceduresResults> resultList, string groupingType)
{
    List<ResultDto> result = new List<ResultDto>();
    switch (groupingType)
    {
        case "Daily":
            result = resultList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Date.Value.Date, x.PlaceName }).Select(x =>
            {
                return new ResultDto
                {
                    Count = x.Count(),
                    Value = x.Sum(x => x.Value),
                    PlaceName = x.Key.PlaceName,
                    GroupingKey = x.Key.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                };
            }).ToList();
            break;

        case "Monthly":
            result = resultList.GroupBy(x => new { Year = x.Date.Value.Year, MonthName = x.Date.Value.ToString("MMM"), x.PlaceName }).Select(x => new ResultDto
            {
                Count = x.Count(),
                Value = x.Sum(x => x.Value),
                PlaceName = x.Key.PlaceName,
                GroupingKey = $"{x.Key.MonthName}-{x.Key.Year}"

            }).ToList();
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your code is using LINQ to Objects to group, filter and order objects in memory. EF is only involved in `.FromSqlRaw(sql, param).AsNoTracking().AsEnumerable();`, where it executes the stored procedure and loads the results in memory. Everything after that is LINQ-to-Objects. Using `AsEnumerable()` probably causes additional delays compared to `ToList()`, because everything is loaded anyway, but subsequent LINQ operations can't use the available `.Count` and `Item[]` members.

Comment: What does the stored procedure do? The LINQ-to-Objects queries are inefficient and often duplicate work, but that will only cause problems if a lot of data is returned. If the stored procedure is inefficient, client-side changes won't improve it. On the other hand, the database server is far better at grouping and ordering. Besides, it looks like only 10 categories of items are used. All others are loaded for no reason.

Comment: `DistinctBy(x => x.Some_Id).OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)` could be a subquery that selects the top 10 `SOME_IDs` by value, eg `WHERE SomeID IN (SELECT TOP 10 DISTINCT SomeID2 From SomeTable ORDER BY Value desc)`

Comment: my stored procedure is doing 4 inner joins with 5 filters and one sub query, and I have huge amount of data.

Comment: what do you suggest to enhance the performance without touching the SP ?

Comment: Why do you assume this would have any effect? If the stored procedure takes 10 minutes and the client code takes 1 second, what's the point? If the stored procedure returns 10K rows but only 100 rows are used, client improvements won't help. Besides what does `huge amount of data.` mean? If it's really huge, you *have* to improve the stored procedure

Comment: Huge amount from 200K - 10M

Comment: In any case, I'd remove `AsEnumerable()` from all queries. In the stored procedure call, I'd use `ToList()` instead of `AsEnumerable()`. I'd replace the Distinct and Grouping with a single Grouping. To calculate the distinct categories you have to iterate over all items anyway, so why do that *twice*? I'd group by `Date.Year` and `Date.Month` instead of generating strings, or even by `new DateTime(Date.Year,Date.Month,1)`. If the LINQ query was well written, I'd consider using PLINQ to run it in parallel

Comment: The stored procedure execution not take more than 5 seconds

Comment: `Huge amount from 200K - 10M` what is that? The rows in the database? Or the stored procedure results? If the stored procedure returns 200K rows, no client-side improvement will help

Comment: @Abdulaziz, why you have intorduced SP, it cannot be converted to the LINQ Query? Grouping should be done on the server side. So, rewrite your SP to do grouping or remove SP, rewrite to LINQ query and do grouping by `IQueryable` GroupBy.

Comment: `The stored procedure execution not take more than 5 seconds` don't process the data on the client then. That's a bug any way you look at it. You're trying to group 200K rows without indexes, with multiple, even duplicate, groups and scans.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it's the other way around. Why use LINQ to do what is a reporting query best run on the server? LINQ isn't the solution to all data access problems, quite the opposite. EF uses LINQ to indirectly generate SQL. That SQL won't be as efficient as a hand-written reporting query. There are a lot of SQL constructs that simply can't be expressed in SQL

Comment: For example that `DISTINCT` and `TOP 10` could be a ranking function.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it's by management decision

Comment: @Abdulaziz if that's management decision then unfortunately they will have to deal with the slow performance here. The GROUP BY, TAKE, ORDER BY Should all be done DB side not in the Client. Moving all of that to the SP will improve your code performance. OR remove the SP and move all to LINQ.

Comment: You can improve performance somewhat by *not* trying to do everything with LINQ. You could index the data using `HashSet` or `Dictionary`. You could use `ToLookup` to generate essentially multi-valued dictionaries from the query output. This way you won't have to scan all objects every time. Just loading 200K entries into a Dictionary though will be slow. Not as slow as scanning 200K rows to find a single item, but still slow. It will also generate a huge object in memory that will take a long time to get GC-d

Comment: Besides, it's unclear what this is trying to do. `DistinctBy` will return the *first* item for every key value. It won't matter what row is used, or if other properties are different. Are you OK with returning essentially a random item? What does ordering by `Value` mean if that happens? That part of the query should return 10 quasi-random items. Is that what you wanted? Load 200K rows to only keep 10? The rest of the query is trying to group those 10 rows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you please combine all of your comments that you wrote in one well formatted answer please, so I can accept the answer.